# Error en la consola de grails

Tags: consola, grails

Cuando entro a mi proyecto y desde una terminal corro el comando grails me da el siguiente error:

```
| Starting daemon.....
grails> | Error Interactive mode exited with error: Error reading input: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading input: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.readLine(GrailsConsole.java:793)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.showPrompt(GrailsConsole.java:779)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.showPrompt(GrailsConsole.java:805)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole$showPrompt$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.showPrompt(InteractiveMode.groovy:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode$showPrompt.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.run(InteractiveMode.groovy:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
| Error Interactive mode exited with error: Error reading input: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
| Daemon Started
```

¿Alguien sabe por que puede ser?
Gracias!

Comment: Ni idea, pero intenta hacer un clean a todo el proyecto, además ejecuta el comando 'grails compile -refresh-dependencies' en cada uno de los modulos para que refresques las dependencias e inténtalo de nuevo

Comment: Hola Adriana! Yo para hacer el clean al proyecto entro a la consola de grail y pongo "clean" en este caso como no me carga como lo puedo hacer? Gracias!

Comment: @AdrianaHernández si ejecuto "grails run-app" la app inicia bien y funciona, lo que no me esta andando es la consola interactiva, la cual me permite crear controllers, clases, etc.. Puede ser problema del Java de mi maquina o algo mas en particular?

Comment: Ejecuta 'grails clean' en cada modulo que tengas y luego 'grails compile -refresh-dependencies', e intenta de nuevo

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Hola! Ejecute el clean y luego el refresh y me sigue dando error :(, exactamente el mismo error.  (Gracias por responder)

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Hola! Ejecute el clean y luego el refresh y me sigue dando error :(, exactamente el mismo error.  (Gracias por responder)